# Scroll to a position in paging library

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-paging, scroll-paging, android-paging-library

I want to scroll to a position in recyclerview working with pagedlist adaptor  but the problem is position to which I want to scroll is not loaded yet so can't scroll to that by using layoutmanager.scrollToPostion()

And placeholders are disabled for my recyclerview  as itemsize is not same

I am fetching data  using room persistence database library

Pls can anyone help me  on how to solve this problem